# How to properly assign NULL value from Bash script to MySQL

Tags: mysql, bash, null

I have a bash script that needs to update MySQL DB.  I have an `if` statement to determine what to put into db, but I think I'm mixing up NULL values with NULL strings.  My code is like following:

```
db_host="localhost"
db_user="user"
db_pass="pass"
db_name="dbname"
MyCmd="mysql -N -h $db_host -u $db_user -p$db_pass -D $db_name"
if [[ $LastCh > 1516980000 ]]; then
  NewCh="$(date -d @$LastCh +"%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S")"
elif [ -n "$NewCh" ]; then
  NewCh=$($MyCmd -e "SELECT MAX(LastChange) FROM Status WHERE IDN=$idn AND LastChange>0")
#  NewCh=$($MyCmd -e "SELECT MAX(LastChange) FROM Status WHERE IDN=$idn AND LastChange IS NOT NULL")
else
  NewCh=NULL
fi    
StatSQL="IDN, Name, LastIP, Activesince, LastChange"
$MyCmd -e "INSERT INTO Status ($StatSQL) VALUES ('$idn', '$name', '$ip', '$activesince', '$NewCh')"
```

So I assign last change to DB if I get it within my script, but if not it needs to get the value from `MAX`imum value of IDN field, but it would display me `NULL` value for `MAX` value, if at least one is `NULL`.  I suspect that it has to do when I assign `NULL` in some cases that is actual string of "NULL" and my `WHERE` clause didn't work so I added extra condition which also didn't work (`.. AND LastChange IS NOT NULL`) but it did with `LastChange>0`, but also not for every case.
1.) How to modify my NewCh variable to be able to carry NULL value? or how to even check what fields in DB are `NULL` and what "NULL" (string)

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) to your script, then paste it at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement all the recommendations made there.

Comment: I have other variables in the script, so would need to add more stuff to get script working, not sure if it makes sense, but I think I got solution with NULLIF()

Comment: make the single quotes part of the `$NewCh` value ... `NewCh="'$(date ...)'"` ... `NewCh="'$($MyCmd ..)'"` ... `NewCh=NULL`; then remove the single quotes from the `INSERT` statement ... `INSERT ... ( ...., '$activesince', $NewCh)"`

Comment: Thanks @markp-fuso that's even easier solution, though I"m not sure if `$(data ...` will be execute through single quotes nor using variable inside '' is possible

Comment: @DenisZ the outer quotes are double quotes so, yes, the `date` should execute as expected; add `typeset -p NewCh` to display the contents of the variable ... you should see something like: `declare -- NewCh="'2023-03-12 13:10:24'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell variables don't have a special null value.  Set them to some specific string that you always want inserted as null (which could be the string NULL or an empty string or something else), and test for that in the insert:

```
insert into tbl (col1,col2) values (nullif('$col1','specialnullvalue'),...
```

Comment: Thanks @ysth.  I think I got you so I could do `NULLIF('$NewCh', 'NULL')` and will assign me NULL value. to the field, and if not mathed will be value of $NewCh variable .